# How to use pots without drainage holes that have an attached saucer

Tags: plant-care

I grow succulents.  I have a pot that has an attached saucer (it cannot be removed). I grow succulents. Should I put a drainage hole through the saucer and the pot?  What is the purpose of this saucer?

Answer (score 2):

If the pot has no drainage holes at all, an attached saucer is purely a stylistic choice with no function whatever. Pots with no drainage holes at all kill plants with some regularity. Probably good for a plastic or silk fake plant.

If the pot has drainage holes into the attached saucer, it's a saucer that doesn't get lost, and is still mostly a style choice. But you can tip the pot and saucer to drain excess water. Or you can give the pot away, or sell it.

On the whole, I don't consider these a great idea .vs. a pot with drainage hole and a separate saucer. Or they are not my style choice...